# Is there a way to count objects currently displayed on the stage using createJS / easelJS?

Tags: javascript, easeljs, createjs

I'm currently creating a program using the createJS suite and have hit a roadblock. I'm "spawning" items on the stage however I wondered if there was a way to count how many currently exist on the stage.

So, for example:

```
if (spawnedItemCount <= 1) {
    spawnItem();
}
```

spawnedItemCount would return the amount of a particular object that is currently being displayed on the stage. If there is only 1 (or less) of these objects then run the spawnItem function. Is this possible at all?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You, are looking for getNumChildren() 
http://createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Container.html#method_getNumChildren

Every container has this method, but it will only return the Number of direct children, no children of children, for that you will have to create a recursive call.

Comment: This works perfectly thank you. Now to fix my code as the results are strange. Thank you.

Comment: For clarification of my previous comment I was using getNumChildren on the stage rather than the container housing all the spawned items I wished to count. Works super perfect now!